# Decodable Fetching Data in another view controller

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I have a viewcontroller that I created. I can login the user into my app from my api. But I am trying to display the data in another view controller. I tried a few different methods but I end up with nil. What I want to display is a username on a card but I get no data.

I tried to pass the data by calling it from the first view controller but it was not working right. I tried to do it in a segue but and then retrieve that variable but I ended up with nil

First View Controller

```
@IBAction func didTapLoginButton() {

    guard
        let username = usernameTextField.text,
        let password = passwordTextField.text
        else { return }

    jsonRequest(username: username, password: password)
}


@IBOutlet weak var addUserButton: UIButton!
@objc private func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
if textField.text?.count == 1 {
    if textField.text?.first == " " {
        textField.text = ""
        return
    }
}
guard
    let userName       = usernameTextField.text,   !userName.isEmpty,
    let passWord    = passwordTextField.text,      !passWord.isEmpty
    else {
        addUserButton.isEnabled = false
        return
}
addUserButton.isEnabled = true

}




func formDataRequest(username: String, password: String) {
    let parameters = ["username": username,
                      "password": password]

    networkingService.request(endpoint: "/login", parameters: parameters) { [weak self] (result) in

        switch result {

        case .success(let user): self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: user)

        case.failure(let error):

            let banner = StatusBarNotificationBanner(title: "Username/Password Incorrect", style: .danger)
            print(error)
            banner.show()
        }
    }
}

func jsonRequest(username:String, password: String) {

    let login = Login(username: username, password: password)

    networkingService.request(endpoint: "/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/", loginObject: login) { [weak self] (result) in

        switch result {

        case .success(let user): self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: user)

        case.failure(let error):

            let banner = StatusBarNotificationBanner(title: "Username/Password Incorrect", style: .danger)
            print(error)
            banner.show()
        }
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let mainAppVC = segue.destination as? SupportCardPartTextViewCardController, let user = sender as? User {

        mainAppVC.user = user
    }
}
}
```

Second Struct

```
     struct User: Decodable {
let token: String
let user_email: String
let user_nicename: String
let user_display_name: Int
}
```

Third One. One I want the data.

```
  class SupportCardPartTextViewCardController: CardPartsViewController {

let user: User?

let cardPartTextView = CardPartTextView(type: .normal)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    cardPartTextView.text = user.usernicename  //Display username here instead!!!!
    setupCardParts([cardPartTextView])
}

}
```

I received nil when I was doing this. I was hoping if there was another way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: User in SupportCardPartTextViewCardController is a local variable- you Never filled it, that’s why it is nil. A solution could be that you write user to UserDefaults and read it in SupportCardPartTextViewCardController from UserDefaults.

Comment: @Chris I will try that. I have not thought of doing that yet